# How to prevent SparkPost from changing urls in emails?

Tags: node.js, sparkpost

I use SparkPost to send emails from my node.js app.

However, all links are converted to urls such as: http://go.sparkpostmail1.com/f/a/EgvUoS2LdGPzMx-AURKwZA~~/AABUGAA~/RgRZK0BSP0EIAGukLuGW3OxXA3NwY1gEAAAAAFkGc2hhcmVkQgoAAVK7SFdpNVEbUhFuaWNvbGFzQGR1cmFuZC5jaAlRBAAAAABEUWh0dHBzOi8vZGlzaGx5Lm1lbnUvZC9XYXNoaW5ndG9uL1JlZ2VudF9UaGFpL0Jhc2lsX0phZS81NjBmMzk5MmQ0YWUxNTAzMDBmZWZmMGIiLEcCe30

I've tried to disable the "click_tracking" like this (see code sample below), but it's still not working. does anyone have an idea to configure SparkPost to send the emails "as is"?

```
var sparky = new SparkPost(process.env.SPARKPOST_API_KEY, {"open_tracking": false, "click_tracking": false});

sparky.transmissions.send({transmissionBody: transmissionBody}, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Whoops! Something went wrong in sendEmail');
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log('sendEmail sent!');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

open and click tracking isn't set when you instantiate the `SparkPost`object, it's done in the `transmissionBody` via the `options` key like so:

```
var SparkPost = require('sparkpost');
var sp = new SparkPost('<YOUR API KEY>');

sp.transmissions.send({
  transmissionBody: {
    options: {
      open_tracking: false,
      click_tracking: false
    },
    content: {
      from: 'testing@sparkpostbox.com',
      subject: 'Hello, World!',
      html:'<html><body><p>Testing SparkPost - the world\'s most awesomest email service!</p></body></html>'
    },
    recipients: [
      {address: '<YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS>'}
    ]
  }
}, function(err, res) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('Whoops! Something went wrong');
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('Woohoo! You just sent your first mailing!');
  }
});
```

Additionally you can see examples for transmissions using node-sparkpost here:
https://github.com/SparkPost/node-sparkpost/tree/master/examples/transmissions

This particular examples includes the options key:
https://github.com/SparkPost/node-sparkpost/blob/master/examples/transmissions/send_transmission_all_fields.js

Answer (score 0):

Variables quoted as `{{ foo }}` are escaped.

Variables quoted as `{{{ foo }}}` are treated as raw HTML.

https://developers.sparkpost.com/api/template-language/#header-html-escaping